# Where can I upload non-human Genotype data?

Tags: genetics, genomics, snp, chickens, data

I have genotype data from few chicken population and I want to (need to) upload them somewhere online with free access. I have searched the web but I haven't found any place for non-human genotype data!

Does anyone have an idea where I can upload it, which is publicly available and user friendly?

bests

Comment: Does this [Website](http://gds.nih.gov/02dr2.html) help?

Comment: Thanks @Chris I checked the link. As long as I understood all those links are for "new variants discovered" or "data for GWAS study". I just have genotypes.

Comment: Isn't here any repository for this animals?

Comment: I did not find any site like that. You can upload the file in your university/lab website.

Comment: I don't think there is an answer for this question, as such a repository for chicken data does not exist.

Comment: @Chris: isn't that a suitable answer then?

Comment: @ChrisStronks This is basically is link answer, which obviously doesn't help. Or do I see this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is necessary to upload to a specialist or targeted repository if none are obvious. For some data types there is an obvious repository such as [dbSNP](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/). It does not sound like such exists.

Probably things have changed since the question was posted, but nonetheless I think that this is a useful question to have answered.

There are a variety of data repositories to which you can upload unstructured data that do not require you to host it yourself:

1. [Open Science Foundation](https://osf.io/): free, non-profit dedicated to ensuring data access and scientific reproducibility.
2. [FigShare](https://figshare.com/): has free accounts, for-profit company.
3. [Dryad](https://datadryad.org/stash): free, non-profit.
4. [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/): non-profit.